# About Inner product space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

[image]

[image]

[image]

So this $\delta$ function  is degree function over Euclidean domain A which is simply defined as

[image]

Now my question is why det L is well defined in first picture and how to get corollary 3.9 and remark that integral lattice is iff $\delta$(det$L$) =0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we define $\det(L)$ is the following.

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis for $L$ as a free $A$-module. Then let $v_1',\ldots,v_n'$ be a different basis for $L$. Let $P$ be the basis change matrix from $\{v_i'\}$ to $\{v_i\}$, so that if $v\in L$ and $v$ has coordinates $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with respect to the $v_i'$, then $v$ has coordinates $Px$ with respect to the $v_i$.

Then $P=(p_{ij})$, where $v_j' = \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}v_i$.

Thus 
$$B(v_i',v_j') = B\left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_{ki}v_k,\sum_{\ell=1}^n p_{\ell j}v_\ell\right)=\sum_{k,\ell}p_{ki}p_{\ell j}B(v_k,v_\ell).$$
Thus as matrices, if we let $C$ be the matrix $C_{k\ell}=B(v_k,v_\ell)$, and $C'$ be the matrix $C'_{ij}=B(v_i',v_j')$, we have $C' = P^T CP$. Thus $\det(C')=\det(C)\det(P)^2$. Since $P$ is an invertible matrix with entries in $A$, $\det(P)\in U(A)$, and $\det(P)^2\in U(A)^2$.

Thus $\det(L)$ is a well-defined class in $K^\times/U(A)^2$.

You mentioned that you figured out Corollary 3.9, so I'll leave this here.

Comment: I don't get the note that is given below corollary can you please explain that? I know that I need to show map from L to L* is isomorphism to show this we take help of matrix form of lattice and then we  need to show that that matrix is invertible to show (L,B) is inner product space.

Comment: @mathsstudent The matrix for the map $L\to L^*$ is given by $B(v_i,v_j)$, so it is invertible if and only if $\det(B(v_i,v_j))$ is a unit in $A$.

Comment: how Lattice $L = V\otimes_k  k[x] $ looks like? Also why every unimodular k[x] lattice is extension from k space what we need to show here? How extension is related to tensor here?

Comment: @mathsstudent Again, these are probably separate questions. The answers (briefly) are: (1) $L$ is free over $k[x]$ because $V$ is free over $k$, and the matrix for the bilinear form will have entries in $k$ and thus have determinant a unit. (2) Are you trying to prove that any unimodular $k[x]$ lattice is of the form $V\otimes_k k[x]$? This should follow from the fact that the units of $k[x]$ are $k^\times$, so in order for the matrix for the bilinear form to have unit determinant, it must have entries in $k$. Extension of scalars from $R$ to $S$ is the functor $S\otimes_R -$.

Comment: @mathsstudent If you have another question, please ask another question. The comments are not the place to ask new questions (they are the place to ask for clarification, but that is not what you are asking for).

Comment: OK I am asking this as questions?

Comment: @mathsstudent Ok, feel free to leave me the link when you do.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166014/about-symmetric-inner-product-space