# About symmetric inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

How lattice $L = V \otimes _k k[x] $ looks like? $L$ is free over $k[x]$ because $V$ is free over $k$ ; why this statement is true? Also I am trying to prove every unimodular $k[x]$ lattice  has form $V \otimes _k k[x]$ how this fact is related to orthogonal basis ? How this statment looks like in matrix version?

Comment: I'm aware of the context since I've answered two of your [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3164399/90543) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3164762/90543) on this topic, but you should probably add the context (and perhaps these links) into the body of this question so that it doesn't get closed.

Comment: No, $V$ is a subset of $L$ via the map $v\mapsto v\otimes 1$.

Comment: @jgon https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187345/extension-of-basis-over-pid can you help me about it?

Answer (score 1):

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $k$ equipped with a nondegenerate bilinear form $B$. Then $L=V\otimes_k k[x]$ is free and $B$ extends to a nondegenerate bilinear form $\tilde{B}$ on $L$ with the same determinant as $B$ (in particular it is an element of $k^\times$).

*Proof.*

$L$ is free because by choosing a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ we get that
$$V\cong k^n$$
for some $n$, so
$$L=V\otimes_k k[x] \cong k^n\otimes_k k[x] \simeq k[x]^n.$$

Under this isomorphism the basis vectors for $L$ are $\ell_i=v_i\otimes 1$.

Now $B$ defines a bilinear form on $L$ by $\tilde{B}(v\otimes p,w\otimes q) = B(v,w)pq$.

Then $$\tilde{B}(\ell_i,\ell_j)=\tilde{B}(v_i\otimes 1,v_j\otimes_1)=B(v_i,v_j).$$
Thus $\det(\tilde{B}(\ell_i,\ell_j))=\det(B(v_i,v_j))$.

**Every unimodular $k[x]$-lattice has this form**

**Edit:** My prior "proof" had an error. This is what's proven in the Theorem in the OP.

**Edit 2:**

To show how the theorem in the question proves every unimodular lattice has this form we do the following.

Let $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n$ be the orthogonal $k[t]$ basis given by the theorem. Define $V=\{\sum_i c_i\ell_i : c_i\in k\}$ and define $B_0$ on $V$ by restricting $B$ to $V$. This is where we use orthogonality! The restriction is well-defined because the $\ell_i$ are orthogonal, so $B(\ell_i,\ell_j)=c_i\delta_{ij}$ for some constants $c_i\in k^\times$.

Then define $V\otimes_k k[t] \to L$ by $\ell_i\otimes p \mapsto p\ell_i$. Since the $\ell_i$ formed a $k[t]$ basis for $L$, this map is an isomorphism of $k[t]$ modules.

Then all we need to check is that the isomorphism sends $\tilde{B_0}$ to $B$. We do this by observing that
$$\tilde{B_0}(\ell_i\otimes p,\ell_j\otimes q) = B_0(\ell_i,\ell_j)pq=B(\ell_i,\ell_j)pq=B(p\ell_i,q\ell_j),$$
as desired.

Comment: Referring to this theorem sir ; I have edited it

Comment: @mathsstudent I'm a bit confused as to what your question is about the theorem.

Comment: my question is how above theorem yields $L = V \otimes _k k[x] $

Comment: @mathsstudent Take the orthogonal $k[x]$-basis that is constructed by the theorem and define $V$ to be the $k$-span of that basis.

Comment: what is the meaning of k span of that basis can you explain that?

Comment: @mathsstudent The $k$-span of a set of vectors in a $k$-vector space is the set of all $k$-linear combinations of that set of vectors.

Comment: but we got orthogonal k[t] basis then how do we get it  as span of k-vector space?

Comment: @mathsstudent $k\subseteq k[t]$, so any $k[t]$-module is automatically a $k$-vector space.

Comment: @mathsstudent Edited.

Comment: thanks alot sir

Comment: @mathsstudent Glad it was helpful :)

Comment: Sir can you explain how restriction is well defined by orthogonal basis and how $V\otimes_k k[t] \to L$ by $\ell_i\otimes p \mapsto p\ell_i$.  is isomorphism of k[t] module?

Comment: restricting B to V means first we compute B(l_i,l_j) and then restrict it to V right?

Comment: @mathsstudent Well, sort of? What it means is that we have $B:L\otimes L \to k[t]$, and we know that $V\otimes V\subseteq L\otimes L$, so we can restrict $B$ to the subset $V\otimes V$. This gives us a function $B|_{V\otimes V}\to k[t]$. Since the codomain is $k[t]$ rather than $k$, in order for this to be an inner product we need to have that the image of $B|_{V\otimes V}$ is actually in $k$. To see this, we compute the matrix of $B$ with respect to the basis $\ell_i$. This gives us the matrix $B(\ell_i,\ell_j)$. Orthogonality tells us that the entries of this matrix are in $k$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168018/tensor-product-map