# If $(m, n) = 1$, then $\dfrac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{\langle (m,n)\rangle}\cong\mathbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

How to show that

> If $(m, n) = 1$, then $\dfrac{\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z}{\langle (m,n)\rangle}\cong\mathbb Z$.
>
> (Note: We consider this in group theory.)

I know that $(m, n) = 1$ means that $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}: mx + ny = 1$.

How to find a group homomorphism $f: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb{Z}$ whose kernel is ${\langle (m,n)\rangle}$?

Comment: Isomorphic as what ?

Comment: Send $f(a,b)=na-mb$. Since any element of $\langle(m,n)\rangle$ is of the form $(mk,nk)$, then $f(mk,nk)=nmk-mnk=0$. From the Bezout's equation that you quoted $f$ is onto. Also, if $f(a,b)=0$, then $na=mb$. Therefore, since $\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)=1$, then $m|a$ and $n|b$. Therefore $(a,b)\in\langle(m,n)\rangle$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension of basis over PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3187345/extension-of-basis-over-pid)

Comment: @user647486 Thanks. Could you please post it as an answer?